отделить время от даты и разбить по часам
При отделении даты от времени проблем не каких не было возможно это связано с форматом.
Формат используемый в таблице выглядит так : 2024-03-23T23:18:42+03:00.
Пробовал отделить так же как и дату от времени. Я это делал так :
    SELECT 
dt::DATE AS "Дата"  

Так же вычитал способ с функцией cast,делал примерно так:
SELECT cast(dt as TIME) as "Время"

Что в первом случае что во втором в ответ приходит 10 цифр
Буду благодарен за пример кода
Ожидаемый результат вывод времени в  формат 24 часа  с округлением до часа

Какая именно СУБД используется? Какой результат ожидается в итоге? Добавьте в вопрос пример и в тегах оставьте только ту СУБД, в который вы работаете

Укажите точно и только одну СУБД, удалите лишние теги. Судя по приведённому коду, у вас PostgreSQL. Формат используемый в таблице выглядит так : 2024-03-23T23:18:42+03:00 PostgreSQL не поддерживает такой формат литерала даты-времени. Либо это явным образом форматированное значение, либо его интерпретация каким-либо языком программирования.

SELECT HOUR(dt) as time

Ларчик просто открывался
